# Automatically update date column in database

Tags: php, mysql

hello I have a page that accepts responses based on if a transaction was successfull or not.

So I am trying to update my database record on a successfull transaction status to paid and also update the start date to the present date and also the expiry date to a one year later date, automatically.

Presently i have been able to update the trasaction status to 'paid' but no clue on how to do this for the dates. I want to do this automatically.

this is what i tried

```
$tnx_ref = $_SESSION['genref'];
$sql = "UPDATE transactions ".
       "SET Transaction_Status = 'paid', Start_Date = 'start', Expiry_Date ='expiry'".
       "WHERE tnx_ref = $tnx_ref ";
```

with this the transaction status was updated to `paid` , startdate to `start` and expirydate to `expiry`

any explaination on how i could go about this

Comment: You would update a date column in the same way. Just set the Start_Date and Expiry_Date to what you want them to be.

Comment: i get u, but i want the exact present date for the start date and a one year ahead date for the expiry date

Comment: Use `NOW()` and `date_add(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `date_add` and `curdate` functions as

```
UPDATE transactions 
SET 
Transaction_Status = 'paid', 
Start_Date = curdate(),
Expiry_Date =date_add(curdate(),interval 1 year)
WHERE tnx_ref = $tnx_ref
```

> Update from the comment "for the expiry date what if i also wanted to
>   minus a day."

```
   UPDATE transactions 
    SET 
    Transaction_Status = 'paid', 
    Start_Date = curdate(),
    Expiry_Date =date_sub(date_add(curdate(),interval 1 year),interval 1 day)
    WHERE tnx_ref = $tnx_ref
```

Comment: ohhh thanks alot, for the expiry date what if i also wanted to minus a day.

Comment: For minus one day its `date_sub(curdate(),interval i day)` so for +1 year -1 day its `date_sub(date_add(curdate(),interval 1 year),interval 1 day)`

Comment: am rili sori, but i would really appreciate if u would update ur code  with the minus one function